# Is there a way to argue that the appearance of the dependence of past states is stochastic behavior?

Tags: measurements, stochastic-processes

Suppose in a particular set of observations that you observe what appears to be a correlation of future results based on past results. Is there a way to be certain that such a phenomena isn't just the result of a only viewing a random snippet in a larger Markov chain that happens to appear biased in that particular set?

Comment: I like this question and hope to see a good answer. It might help to give a more explicit example though, because otherwise it's a bit vague.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer (or one at all) after a few days, you may want to try over at [stats.se]

Comment: Indeed this doesn't seem specific to physics, more of a time series analysis question, Cross Validated may be a better choice.

Comment: How do you observe something outside the bounds of physics though? Isn't it an intrinsic limitation upon which all physical models are built?

Comment: One could ask the original question about time series data from for instance economics as well as from physics. The degree to which economic data is ultimately generated by physics processes is interesting, but an entirely separate question IMO.